# How can I get asynchronous post data from a webpage with WebClient?

Tags: c#, webclient

A website I'm reading with `WebClient` returns a JSON object after loading.  I can press a button on the website to initiate an async postback, and the JSON object is returned:

[image]

When I try to post to the same URL as the JSON data, I get a full postback and the entire page is returned, rather than just the JSON data.

My code is simply this:

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    reqparm.Add("limit", "1000");
    byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("https://somewebsite.org/doe/search/resultData", "POST", reqparm);
    string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that the postback is sent with proper headers including cookies to aid the server identifying the fact it's a postback. Your simplistic `WebClient` code doesn't follow this scheme, so the server sends a full page response.

Comment: As it turns out, I (embarrassingly) had the wrong URL in the `.UploadValues` method.